# App shows black screen in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I am developing iOS app in which i have side menu with TabBar,

I have settled My `sidemenu container viewController` as IntitalViewController of my app.

Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"navigationController"];
    UIViewController *leftSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftSideMenuViewController"];


    [container setLeftMenuViewController:leftSideMenuViewController];

    [container setCenterViewController:navigationController];


    return YES;
}
```

Here is the Design of my Storybaord:

[image]

When i run my app i see a black screen with no error

**Where i am making mistake, please help**

***Thanks in adavnnce !!***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give try to this (after seeing your code):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    self.window.rootViewController=[[MFSideMenuContainerViewController alloc]init];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = (MFSideMenuContainerViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    UITabBarController *tabController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBarController"];

    UIViewController *leftSideMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"leftSideMenuViewController"];



    [container setLeftMenuViewController:leftSideMenuViewController];

    [container setCenterViewController:tabController];


    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

> Also give the respective id's to view controllers in storyboard ( for tabBar, navigation)
>   and don't forget to give root view controller for navigation
>   controller.

Comment: did you made any changes any MFSideMenuContainer class?

Comment: can i have your mail id?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109216/discussion-between-suhas-patil-and-krunal).